# How do I make sure VS Code (v 1.45.1) is using the latest version of pandas, Numpy, and sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

I installed pandas through the terminal using the command pip3 install pandas and the latest version of the package was downloaded (v 1.14.0) and installed but when I check the pandas version on VS Code it says it is using version (1.0.4). How do I change this? Will working with an outdated version of pandas cause me any problems?

Thanks.

Comment: 1.0.4 *is* the latest version of Pandas. Where are you seeing 1.14.0?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really VSC's fault. You just have to update your package via command prompt or terminal, depending on the OS that you use. To update a package simply do:

```
pip install [package_name] --upgrade
```

That should do the trick. Hope that helps.